# how limit start value come from other table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following my sql query, I want to take limit start index from the other table, How could I do it?

```
  SELECT std.totalmarks 
    FROM student as std  
   WHERE std.status=1 
ORDER BY (std.datetime) ASC 
   LIMIT ( 
          SELECT us.startnum 
            FROM user AS us 
           WHERE us.username='abc'
          ),10
```

Comment: Do you receiving any error?

Comment: I don't think `limit` allows select statement in offset

Comment: yes error. yes I know not it is not allowed select in limit, I am asking is it possible?

Comment: @Alexander what data you need? I write complete query in which I have problem and also give statement than what you need for that? I think you need database?

Comment: table structure and explanation on what do you need to get would be nice

Comment: I think query explain the structure of tables. I have only problem how to give first parameter of limit from other table. It is a simple statement no need to any thing else if any one have it's answer can give, if not commenting like you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select q.totalmarks from
(
SELECT *,@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM student as std JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
WHERE std.status=1
ORDER BY (std.datetime) ASC
) q
where row_number>( 
          SELECT us.startnum 
            FROM user AS us 
           WHERE us.username='abc'
          )
limit 10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from
   (SELECT std.totalmarks, numstart.startnum, @n:=@n+1 as number 
    FROM student as std,
         (SELECT us.startnum 
            FROM user AS us 
           WHERE us.username='abc') as numstart,
         (SELECT @n:=0) sess_var
    WHERE std.status=1 
    ORDER BY (std.datetime) ASC) res
where number>=startnum 
LIMIT 0,10
```